# EmailConfirmation causes error

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, asynchronous, identity

I am fairly new to threading and C#. I'm trying to implement Identity, I run into a problem: when I register a user and send the confirmation link, clicking on the link causes an exception:

I try to do my best to simplify my code to explain problem.

so I have `AccountController` in my Controllers of MVC project:

```csharp
namespace SolwayOrder.Controllers {
    public class AccountController: Controller {
       private readonly ApplicationUserManager _manager;
       private readonly SignInManager < IdentityUser, string > _signIn;
       private readonly RoleManager < IdentityRole, int > _roleManager;

       public AccountController(
        ApplicationUserManager manager,
        SignInManager < IdentityUser, string > signIn,
        RoleManager < IdentityRole, int > roleManager
       ) {
        _manager = manager;
        _signIn = signIn;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
       }

       [HttpPost]
       [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
       public async Task < ActionResult > Register(RegisterModel model, string returnUrl) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
         var user = new IdentityUser(model.Email);
         var result = await _manager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
         if (result.Succeeded) {
          var code = await _manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(model.Email);              var callbackUrl = Url.Action(
           "ConfirmEmail", "Account",
           new {
            userId = model.Email, code = code
           },
           protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

          await _manager.SendEmailAsync(model.Email,
           "Confirm your account",
           "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
          return Content("Please confirm your account. Link was sent to " + model.Email);
         }
        }
        return View();
       }


       [HttpGet]
       public async Task < ActionResult > ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code) {
        if (userId == null || code == null) return View("Register"); //error
        var result = await _manager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
        if (result.Succeeded) {
         return View();
        }
        return View("Register");
       }
    }
}
```

The problem arise when I click the link which I got on Email:

```
A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Source Error: 


Line 29: 
Line 30:         public async Task<User> FindByUserNameAsync(string username) {
Line 31:             return await Set.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Email == username);
Line 32:         }
Line 33: 

Source File: C:\Users\Solway\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SolwayOrder\SolwayOrder.Repo\Repositories\UserRepository.cs    Line: 31
```

I modified it so everywhere for asynchronous methods, where Task is returned, I have async and await.

sorry couldn't simplify the question more, I think this is common pattern and should be understandable. if not here's a link to full project:
[DropBox Link To project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sognj39aafqz7ee/SolwayOrder.rar?dl=0)

```
full stack:


[NotSupportedException: A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.ThrowingMonitor.EnsureNotEntered() +72
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>.GetAsyncEnumerator() +22
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.<FirstOrDefaultAsync>d__25`1.MoveNext() +114
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
   SolwayOrder.Repo.<FindByUserNameAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Solway\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SolwayOrder\SolwayOrder.Repo\Repositories\UserRepository.cs:31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
   SolwayOrder.Service.<FindUserByNameAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Solway\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SolwayOrder\SolwayOrder.Service\Security.cs:40
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
   SolwayOrder.Identity.<FindByNameAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Solway\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SolwayOrder\SolwayOrder\Identity\UserStore.cs:46
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<ValidateUserName>d__4.MoveNext() +589
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<ValidateAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +293
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<UpdateAsync>d__5.MoveNext() +295
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<ConfirmEmailAsync>d__c5.MoveNext() +1100
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
   SolwayOrder.Controllers.<ConfirmEmail>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Solway\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\SolwayOrder\SolwayOrder\Controllers\AccountController.cs:88
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9987157
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

what really surprises me is that if I set breakpoint on EmailConfirm Controller, and go step by step, everything goes smooth and perfect, no exception.

Comment: When I set breakpoint to FindByNameAsync and go line by line with F11, no errors occur.

Comment: From my experience, the exception you're seeing is typical when using an instance of an entity framework context on multiple threads simultaneously.

Comment: At least post full stack trace of exception.

Comment: @Evk I edited it.

Comment: Ensure that you do not miss awaiting started task anywhere in your application. In some cases it will be underlined with warning "Because this call is not awaited, ..." (for example this happens in your `GenerateAsync` method in user store.

Comment: @Evk, I modified code, so that nowhere occurs async method without "async" and "await" keywords. also modified original question. the problem still persists

Comment: I didn't read you code but if what CodeFuller says is true (that you have singleton instance of your db context, not even instance per request) - that should be fixed.

Comment: Why singleton is wrong? I mean, I try to code the "correct way" and listened to many arguments why I should use it. so is singleton wrong?

Comment: The last sentence of the exception message tells you why a singleton context is wrong.

Comment: @GertArnold, so you suggest me to create and dispose context for every 'savechange'?

Comment: To put it more exactly: for each request. If you use an IoC container it should have an option for life cycle per request.

Comment: Singleton is wrong here just because Entity Framework database context is not thread safe. When accessing it from multiple threads at the same time (and that is what happens when multiple requests hit your api) - anything can happen, because it was just not designed for this use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your repository classes (`SolwayOrder.Repo.Repository`, `SolwayOrder.Repo.UserRepository`, `SolwayOrder.Repo.UnitOfWork`) you keep Singletone instance of `AppDbContext` in private field and use it in all operations.

If several concurrent requests are executing, you catch that exception with clear message 'A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed'.

As a rule you should create instance of a context in each operation and dispose it after the use. Do not be afraid of performance degradation due to connection opening for every context creation. Entity Framework is built over ADO.NET that uses [connection pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-pooling). Performance should not degrade comparing to Singleton context.

For example your `SaveChangesAsync` method

```
public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

should be rewritten as:

```
public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using (var ctx = new AppDbContext())
    {
        return await ctx.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Note, that you can't keep the method non-async as previously. As far as your context is disposed in the method, you should await for SaveChangesAsync operation to complete.

Comment: I don't want to use several instances of DbContext. I use unit of work(unity) and repository Patern. as for "await" I put it with "async" but it waits forever.

Comment: Apparently singleton shouldn't be implemented. I will read more about singleton and IOC and will reward this answer if this is the way I should do it. meanwhile I will mark it as an answer. ty

Answer (score 2):

> adding `await` didn't help.

Just to be clear, aside from "*adding `await`*", you also need to

- make the function `async`
- return the `IdentityUser`

The standard code would be

```
    public async Task<IdentityUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName) {
        var user = await _security.FindUserByNameAsync(userName);

        return getIdentityUser(user);

    }
```

Notice that you should use "*`async` all the way*", so also your `FindUserByNameAsync` sould read

```
    public async Task<User> FindUserByNameAsync(string userName) {
        return await _unitOfWork.UserRepository.FindByUserNameAsync(userName);
    }
```

Comment: modified everything as you explained. but the same exception.
Source Error: 

`Line 44: 
Line 45:         public async Task<IdentityUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName) {
Line 46:             var user = _security.FindUserByNameAsync(userName).Result;
Line 47: 
Line 48:             return await Task.FromResult<IdentityUser>(getIdentityUser(user))`

Comment: I edited question after changing code as you explained.