# ObjectDisposedException in M2Mqtt Event Handler of ASP.Net.Core 2 Application

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, mqtt

I'm using Dot.Net Core 2 with EntityFramework 2.0.1 and M2Mqtt Client (M2MqttDotnetCore 1.0.7).  When content is received by the M2Mqtt Client, it should store it into a database, but at this point it throws the following error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: "Cannot access a disposed object.

I can call the repository from a controller and it works fine. How can I get it to work in the Mqtt event handler? What am I missing?

```
public class MyRepository : IRepository
{
  private readonly MyContext _context;
  public MyRepository(MyContext context)
  {
    _context = context;
  }
  public void AddMyItem(Item item)
  {
     _context.Items.Add(item) //Throws error at this line
  }
}
```

The Startup.cs file contains

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
services.AddScoped<IRepository, MyRepository>();
services.AddScoped<IMqttApiService, MqttApiService>();
...
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
          MyContext myContext, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
          ...
          app.UseMvc();           
          mqttApiService = serviceProvider.GetService<IMqttApiService>();
          mqttApiService.Start();
        }
}
```

MqttApiService.cs

```
public class MqttApiService : IMqttApiService
    {
        private MqttClient _client;
        private readonly IRepository _repo;

        public MqttApiService(IRepository repository)
        {
            _repo = repository;
        }

        ~MqttApiService()
        {
            _client.Disconnect();   
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            string hostname = "localhost";
            _client = new MqttClient(hostname);
            _client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;
            string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var qosLevels = new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE };
            var topics = new String[] { "/home/temperature" };
            _client.Subscribe(topics, qosLevels);
            _client.Connect(clientId);
        }

        private void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
        {
            string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Item item = new Item {name = result};
            _repo.AddMyItem(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You inject instance of `DbContext` to repository class and use it repeatedly for different operations. That's incorrect usage of `DbContext`. The correct way is to create instance of a `DbContext` in each operation and dispose it right after the use.

Another problem that you could face, except `ObjectDisposedException`, is `NotSupportedException` if you try to use your repository from several simultaneous threads. Class of `DbContext` just don't support simultaneous operations on the same instance. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47387932/5740031) for this problem here.

Do not be afraid of performance degradation due to connection opening for every context creation. Entity Framework is built over ADO.NET that uses connection pooling. Performance should not degrade comparing to Singleton context.

Here's example of changed `AddMyItem()` method:

```
public void AddMyItem(Item item)
{
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        context.Items.Add(item);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but breaks incapsulation and defeats the purpose of using dependency injection.  The repository is also a separate library which has no access to the connection string which is required to re-instantiate the Context. (var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>(); builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString); using (var context = new MyContext(builder.Options)) ...

Comment: If it's an issue for you, you could pass some sort of DbContext factory to the constructor. It could be either a separate interface (`IContextFactory`) or something simple as `Func<MyContext>`. Check this [article](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/), it has detailed description of different ways to manage DbContext lifetime with their pros and cons.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is very useful and I therefore marked this answer up.  After playing around this morning trying out the answers and different stuff, I did eventually find a solution that seems to work without having to change the repository and keeping everything in scoped mode (see my answer below).   Since each event runs in it's own thread I realised thanks to the answers here that I needed to get the repository inside the event and not outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

> > I can call the repository from a controller and it works fine. How can I get it to work in the Mqtt event handler?

You registered the repository to be injected in your HTTP Request scope.  If you somehow access it after the Request is complete, you should expect this error.  So after the controller spins up the MQTT service, it calls Dispose on the scoped services.  The only reason this is working as much as it is is that the MQTT service isn't IDisposable, and has a finalizer instead.

Looks like both of these services should have their DI registration changed.  EG the MQTT service a singleton, and the repository transient.  Then the MQTT service would manage the lifecycle of the repository instance.

Comment: This causes a System.InvalidOperationException: "Cannot consume scoped service 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions' from singleton IMqttApiService" even though I called AddDbContext with ServiceLifetime.Transient parameter and used AddTransient for the Repository.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that doesn't require me to change the repository and keep everything in scoped mode.

I first changed the MqttApiService adding IServiceProvider:

```
private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
public MqttApiService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}
```

Then I use GetService from the ServiceProvider to get the injected Repository

```
private void client_MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
{
  _repo = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IRepository) as IRepository
  string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message);
  Item item = new Item {name = result};
  _repo.AddMyItem(item);
}
```

This solution seems to work.